# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.eav_attribute' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `eav_attribute`

Tags: error

he migrado mi pag web magento de un servidor a otro, el problema surgio al momento de conectar la base de datos y me salta ese error.

Error in file:

> "C:\xampp\htdocs\fabri\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\sql\catalog_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0.19.1.2-1.6.0.0.19.1.3.php"
>   - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.eav_attribute' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE
>   `eav_attribute`

Trace:

> 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fabri\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644):
>   Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
>
> 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fabri\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade',
>   '1.6.0.0.19.1.2', '1.6.0.0.19.1.5')
>
> 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\fabri\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0.19.1.2',
>   '1.6.0.0.19.1.5')
>
> 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\fabri\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
>
> 4 C:\xampp\htdocs\fabri\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
>
> 5 C:\xampp\htdocs\fabri\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
>
> 6 C:\xampp\htdocs\fabri\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> 7 C:\xampp\htdocs\fabri\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> 8 {main}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the table does exist in your new database and if it exists in your backup file (database creation scripts). If not, take a new database dump from your previous hosting provider and try to import it again.